# Is it okay to repeatedly switch game cartridges on a 3DS?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds

I have been trading between two Pokémon games by myself making use of the GTS: after offering a trade on Ultra sun, I switched to Sun and quickly located my own Pokémon in order to trade with myself to get a Pokémon from sun to my ultra sun.

I did this a few times, but I'm wondering if it's good or bad for the game or system to quickly and repeatedly switch between games when only playing them for a short time.

Comment: The hardware will certainly not like it

Comment: @dly Mind expanding that and turning it into an answer?

Answer (score 1):

I'm happy for someone to provide a more technical answer with proofs on whether or not this is good for the console. Going purely by the experiences of myself and others I know, we have never observed the frequent* switching of games to do harm to our consoles, provided you are correctly closing the software and gently removing the cartridge and not just yanking it out while mid-game.

In your situation specifically, I'd be more concerned with people on the GTS intercepting your self-trade and you losing a Pokemon! It might be worth looking into Pokemon Bank as an alternative approach.

*-Frequent being once every ~2 minutes. However long it takes to start the game and connect to the GTS.

Comment: Ummm I catch a Pokémon from route on ultra and put it on gts and accept the trade in sun so loosing Pokémon isn't a problem

Comment: I just added that in case you weren't aware of Pokemon Bank; trades can be found and accepted faster than one can switch games. Just an extra bit of info; not the main point of the answer :) .

Comment: I am not allowed to have poke bank